# ¿Cómo crear virtualhost en apache usando una misma interfaz y que cada virtualhost escuche por un puerto concreto?

Tags: apache, servidor, puertos

Tengo el siguiente problema, quiero crear dos virtualhost que resuelvan por nombre con apache, uno de ellos atenderá las peticiones por el puerto 80, y el otro por el 8080. He conseguido hacer esto resolviendo por dirección con dos interfaces de la siguiente forma, adjunto ***parte*** del fichero httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "D:/servidor/apache"

Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 192.168.1.2:80
Listen 192.168.1.1:8080

#{CONTENIDO OMITIDO}

#PRIVADO.COM

<virtualhost 192.168.1.1:8080>
DocumentRoot "C:/privado"
ServerName "www.privado.com"
<Directory "C:/privado">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

</virtualhost>


#PUBLICO.COM

<virtualhost 192.168.1.2:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/publico"
ServerName "www.publico.com"
<Directory "D:/publico">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</virtualhost>

#DASHBOARD

<virtualhost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/servidor/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</virtualhost>
```

Así queda configurado el archivo hosts en mi sistema (windows 7):

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#127.0.0.1           localhost
#::1                 localhost

192.168.1.1         www.privado.com
192.168.1.2         www.publico.com
```

El problema viene cuando intento resolver por nombre, he intentado algo así:

```
ServerRoot "D:/servidor/apache"

Listen 80
Listen 8080

 #{CONTENIDO OMITIDO}

#PRIVADO.COM

<virtualhost www.privado.com:8080>
DocumentRoot "C:/privado"
ServerName "www.privado.com"
<Directory "C:/privado">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

</virtualhost>


#PUBLICO.COM

<virtualhost www.publico.com:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/publico"
ServerName "www.publico.com"
<Directory "D:/publico">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</virtualhost>

#DASHBOARD

<virtualhost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/servidor/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</virtualhost>
```

Quedando ahora el fichero hosts así:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#127.0.0.1           localhost
#::1                 localhost

127.0.0.1        www.privado.com
127.0.0.1        www.publico.com
```

De esta forma **AMBOS** atienden por el 80 y por el 8080 y quiero que www.privado.com vaya por el 8080 y www.publico.com por el 80. No consigó dar con el error. 
Gracias de antemano, un saludo a toda la comunidad.

EDITO DE NUEVO

Después de un rato probando posibles soluciones ésta parece que funciona con el propósito que deseo:

```
#PRIVADO

<virtualhost 192.168.1.1:8080>
DocumentRoot "C:/privado"
ServerName "www.privado.com"
<Directory "C:/privado">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</virtualhost>

#ESTE VIRTUALHOST SÓLO SIRVE PARA REDIRIGIR AL PUERTO CORRECTO
<virtualhost 192.168.1.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/privado"
ServerName "www.privado.com"
Redirect permanent / http://www.privado.com:8080
<Directory "C:/privado">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</virtualhost>


#PUBLICO

<virtualhost 192.168.1.1:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/publico"
ServerName "www.publico.com"
<Directory "D:/publico">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</virtualhost>

#ESTE VIRTUALHOST SÓLO SIRVE PARA REDIRIGIR AL PUERTO CORRECTO
<virtualhost 192.168.1.1:8080>
DocumentRoot "D:/publico"
ServerName "www.publico.com"
Redirect permanent / http://www.publico.com:80
<Directory "D:/publico">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
</virtualhost>

#DASHBOARD

NameVirtualHost localhost:80
<virtualhost localhost:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/servidor/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</virtualhost>
```

Como se puede observar estoy resolviendo por dirección, una misma dirección para los dos host virtuales. Lo que he hecho es usar la directiva *Redirect* para redireccionar a la versión de la página por el puerto que quiero, ahora bien, ¿Esta es la forma correcta de hacer ésto?. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Ambos host virtuales están en la misma máquina física (servidor)? tengo entendido que puedes usar la misma dirección IP, incluso el mismo puerto. Apache automáticamente selecciona el host en función del dominio al que intentas acceder. mira este enlace [como configurar vhost](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-virtual-host-de-apache-en-ubuntu-14-04-lts-es)